# Diferencia entre “que” y “quien”

Tags: pronombres

> 1. El autor **quien** acaba de llegar de Francia firmó muchos libros.
> 2. El hombre **que** sale del banco ahora lleva una maleta.

¿Podría cambiar **quien** por **que** en 1 y **que** por **quien** en 2?
Si no, ¿por qué?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La respuesta es *no* en ambos casos. La oración número 1 es gramaticalmente incorrecta. La número 2 es correcta y se volvería incorrecta si cambiases *que* por *quien*.

La razón es que *quien* no puede usarse como pronombre relativo para comenzar una frase subordinada de esta clase. Si hay un sustantivo o una frase nominal (como *el autor* o *el hombre*) entonces *quien* sólo puede usarse para introducir una frase subordinada explicativa. Este tipo de frase se pronuncia con una pausa en el habla, y en la escritura se separa con comas:

> *El autor, quien acaba de llegar de Francia, firmó muchos libros.*

Lo que indica que una frase subordinada es explicativa es que puedes borrarla (quitarla totalmente) y lo que queda sigue significando lo mismo, menos la aclaración, explicación o detalle que introducías con la subordinada:

> *El autor firmó muchos libros.*

En cambio, una frase subordinada con *que* puede ser explicativa o no. Si es explicativa, funciona igual que con *quien*:

> *El autor, que acaba de llegar de Francia, firmó muchos libros.*

Si no es explicativa, en cambio, funciona de manera parecida a un demostrativo o adjetivo calificativo, definiendo el sujeto:

> *El autor que acaba de llegar de Francia firmó muchos libros.*

En este caso, la frase *que acaba de llegar de Francia* no es un detalle que puedas borrar, sino lo que le comunica al oyente a qué autor te refieres: es *el que acaba de llegar de Francia* y no otro autor cualquiera. Es un detalle que define, igual que si dijeras *el autor de Game of Thrones* o *el autor más vendido del mundo*.

*Quien* sí se puede usar en subordinadas no explicativas si va precedido de una preposición:

> *El autor a quien vi en el avión firmó muchos libros.*
>
> *El hombre de quien me hablaste estaba en la librería.*

El castellano, como ves, no funciona en este caso como el inglés (donde siempre puedes usar *who* para las subordinadas que se refieren a personas) ni como el francés (donde debes usar *qui* en las subordinadas que se refieran a personas y *que* en las otras) ni como el alemán (donde no hay diferencia clara entre las subordinadas explicativas y no explicativas).

Answer (score 1):

El [diccionario](http://dle.rae.es/?w=diccionario) de la Real Academia Española dice para los usos pertinentes:

> [**quien**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UpfJQop)
>   Del lat. quem, acus. de qui.
>
> Puede escribirse con acento en acep. 3.
>
> 1. pron. relat. m. y f. El que, el cual o que. U. con antecedente referido a personas. Este es el escritor **de quien** te hablé. U. **sin preposición solo encabeza oraciones explicativas.** **El escritor invitado, quien trató ampliamente esa cuestión, es un especialista en la materia.**
> 2. pron. relat. m. y f. El que o aquel que. U. sin antecedente expreso referido a personas. No dejes entrar a quienes lleguen tarde.
> 3. pron. relat. m. y f. Alguien que o nadie que. U. sin antecedente expreso generalmente con los verbos tener y haber. ¿Hay quien dé más? No hay quien pueda con él. U. m. en sing.
>
> quien más quien menos
>
> 1. loc. pronom. Unos más y otros menos. En estos días quien más quien menos se siente abrumado por el trabajo.

> QUE
>   1. pron. relat. m., f. y n. **Introduce una oración relativa y refiere a un antecedente expreso, generalmente nominal**. Se pondrá los vestidos que tú elijas. Ella, que finalmente no vino, tenía un compromiso.

La frase: El autor quien acaba de llegar de Francia firmó muchos libros.

no está correcta, porque no encabeza un oración explicativa. Tendría que ser:

- El autor que acaba de llegar de Francia firmó muchos libros.

o

Aquí **quien** encabeza una oración explicativa:

- El autor, quien vi en la calle, firmó muchos libros.